# CreateDIBSection + 16 bit system color

Tags: winapi

This code works perfect on 32 bit system color (Windows 7),
but it doesn't work on 16 bit color - menu bitmaps not transparent!!!:

```
...
HBITMAP rv = rgb(hsrc, 16);
...

HBITMAP rgb(HBITMAP hsrc, WORD wBitsPixel) {

    HBITMAP hold = NULL;
    HDC hdcsrc = NULL, hdc = NULL;
    BITMAP bmp = {0};
    HBITMAP dib = NULL;
    UCHAR *dst = NULL, *src = NULL, *tmp = NULL;
    UCHAR alpha;
    int bpl;
    ULONG x, y;
    DWORD bmp_size = 0;
    HANDLE hdib = NULL;
    char *lpbitmap = NULL;
    int rv = 0;


    hdc    = GetDC(m_hMainDlg);
    hdcsrc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    hold   = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcsrc, hsrc);
    rv     = GetObject(hsrc, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmp);

    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi = {0};
    bi.biSize          = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bi.biWidth         = bmp.bmWidth;;
    bi.biHeight        = bmp.bmHeight;
    bi.biPlanes        = 1;
    bi.biBitCount      = wBitsPixel;
    bi.biCompression   = BI_RGB;
    bi.biSizeImage     = 0;
    bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biClrUsed       = 0;
    bi.biClrImportant  = 0;

    bmp_size = ((bmp.bmWidth * bi.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4 * bmp.bmHeight;
    hdib = GlobalAlloc(GHND, bmp_size);

    lpbitmap = (char *)GlobalLock(hdib);

    /* Get bits of source bitmap. */
    GetDIBits(hdcsrc, hsrc, 0, bmp.bmHeight, lpbitmap, (BITMAPINFO *)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    /* For destination bitmap */
    BITMAPINFO bmi = {0};
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSize          = sizeof(BITMAPINFO);
    bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth         = bmp.bmWidth;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight        = bmp.bmHeight;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes        = 1;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount      = wBitsPixel;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression   = BI_RGB;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage     = 0;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biClrUsed       = 0;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biClrImportant  = 0;

    dib = CreateDIBSection(NULL, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void **)&dst, NULL, 0);

    bpl = 4 * bmp.bmWidth; /* bytes per line */
    src = (UCHAR *)lpbitmap;
    for (y = 0; y < bmp.bmHeight; y++, src += bpl) {
        tmp = src;
        for (x = 0; x < bmp.bmWidth; x++) {
            alpha  = tmp[3];

            dst[0] = tmp[0] * alpha / 255;
            dst[1] = tmp[1] * alpha / 255;
            dst[2] = tmp[2] * alpha / 255;
            dst[3] = alpha;

            dst += 4;
            tmp += 4;
        }
    }

    // free resources
    ReleaseDC(m_hMainDlg, hdc);
    SelectObject(hdcsrc, hold);
    DeleteDC(hdcsrc);
    GlobalUnlock(hdib);
    GlobalFree(hdib);

    return dib;
}
```

Comment: Um, 16bpp bitmaps don't have an alpha channel. You created a 16bpp bitmap but are treating it like a 32bpp bitmap, which doesn't work (and also is a buffer overflow).

Comment: I need transparent bitmaps on 16 bit color, what can I do?

Comment: Use a 32bpp bitmap. You can display 32bpp bitmaps on 16-bit devices. They just lose some color resolution.

Comment: Can I have some code? Or some example?

Comment: You already wrote the code above. Just use wBitsPixel=32.

Comment: Bitmaps become invisible

Comment: Debug why. Check the alpha channel of hsrc.

Comment: How can I check the alpha channel of hsrc?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're asking how to do something you're already doing: `alpha  = tmp[3];`.

Comment: `TRACE("dst[0]=%d,  dst[1]=%d,  dst[2]=%d,  dst[3]=%d\n",  dst[0], dst[1], dst[2], dst[3]);

 /******* dst[0]=0, dst[1]=0, dst[2]=0, dst[3]=0 *******/`

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting here. You already printed the result of your investigation. Now you get to figure out why the alpha channel is zero.

Comment: Can you explain me? why alpha channel is zero? GetLastError() after CreateDIBSection() is zero. What's wrong?

Comment: I don't know why the alpha channel is zero. It's your bitmap. I don't know where you got it from. Only you can answer the question. (Don't expect me to answer it.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But, why on 32-bit system color apha channel is presents? It's the same "my.bmp" file?

Comment: There is probably something bit-depth-specific about the way you loaded it, then.

Comment: that is bitmap http://zalil.ru/34253117